# Python: Using a Dropdown form to redircect

Tags: python, forms, redirect, drop-down-menu

I am pretty new to coding, and am working on a project where I want to have a homepage, with a form that is a drop down selector with a submit button.   Once the correct "state" is selected from the dropdown, and "submit" is clicked, I want to redirect to that state page.   I believe I have everything set up correct, but I am stumped on the code for my "stateselector" handler that I am redirecting with.   I am pulling "state" paramte from the form, but I do not know how to apply it to redirect to the correct state handler.  the Any suggestions?:

MY PYTHON:

```
import os
import jinja2
import webapp2

template_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates")
jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(loader = jinja2.FileSystemLoader(template_dir), autoescape = True)

class Handler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def write(self, *a, **kw):
    self.response.out.write(*a, **kw)

def render_str(self, template, **params):
    t = jinja_env.get_template(template)
    return t.render(params)  

def render(self, template, **kw):
    self.write(self.render_str(template, **kw))

class Mainpage(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html")

class StateSelector(Handler):
def get (self):
    state = self.request.get("state")
    state = 




class State1(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html")  

class State2(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html") 

class State3(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html")

class State4(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html") 

class State5(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html") 

class State6(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html") 

class State7(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html") 

class State8(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html") 

class State9(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html") 

class State10(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html") 

class State11(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html") 

class State12(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html")

class State13(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html")        

class State14(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html")

class State15(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html")

class State16(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html")

class State17(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html")

class State18(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html")                        

class State19(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html")

class State20(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html")

class State21(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html")

class State22(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html")

class State23(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html")

class State24(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html")

class State25(Handler):
def get(self):
    self.render("mainpage.html")                                        


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([("/", Mainpage),
                         ("/stateselector", StateSelector),
                         ("/state1", State1),
                         ("/state2", State2),
                         ("/state3", State3),
                         ("/state4", State4),
                         ("/state5", State5),
                         ("/state6", State6),
                         ("/state7", State7),
                         ("/state8", State8),
                         ("/state9", State9),
                         ("/state10", State10),
                         ("/state11", State11),
                         ("/state12", State12),
                         ("/state13", State13),
                         ("/state14", State14),
                         ("/state15", State15),
                         ("/state16", State16),
                         ("/state17", State17), 
                         ("/state18", State18),
                         ("/state19", State19),
                         ("/state20", State20),
                         ("/state21", State21),
                         ("/state22", State22),
                         ("/state23", State23),
                         ("/state24", State24),
                         ("/state25", State25)],
                         debug=True)
```

And my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Changeyourparty.org</title>    
</head>

<body>
<div>
    SUMMARY:
    The Purpose of .......
</div>

<div>
<form action="/stateselector">
    <label>Select Your State:
        <select name="state">
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
            <option>5</option>
            <option>6</option>
            <option>7</option>
            <option>8</option>
            <option>9</option>
            <option>10</option>
            <option>11</option>
            <option>13</option>
            <option>14</option>
            <option>15</option>
            <option>16</option>
            <option>17</option>
            <option>18</option>
            <option>19</option>
            <option>20</option>
            <option>21</option>
            <option>22</option>
            <option>23</option>
            <option>24</option>
            <option>25</option>
        </select>
    </label>    
    <input type="submit">
</form>


</div>
```